# How to smooth graph lines in R and add a line of best fit

Tags: r, line, smoothing

```html
ggline(Titration.Aug.9,x="Dilution",y="X..bound",color="Sample")+
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10",labels=trans_format("log10",math_format(10^x)),minor_breaks=10^(seq(0,7, by=0.25)))+
  theme_minimal()+labs(x="Dilution",y="% Bound")+
  scale_color_brewer(type="Sample",palette="Set1")
```

I have this line of code and it generates the graph I want. The only things I need to add to it now are smoother lines for the plot. I though maybe using geom_smooth(aes(linetype=X..bound)) but that just gives me a shaded line of best fit and an error message of "a continuous variable cannot be mapped to livetype" I suspect maybe because I made the x-axis a log scale but left the y scale a linear scale. How do I smoothen out my graph lines? Also how do I add a line of best fit that is sigmoidal to the graph? I don't need any other background color with it like in some commands I have tried; I just need a plane line of best fit that is able to be labeled on the side of the graph in the legend. Any help is appreciated!! Thank you in advance :)

Graph data

```
structure(list(Dilution = c(300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 
72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 
300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 
2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 
24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 
218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 
900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 
8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L), X..bound = c(52.74, 40.31, 30.63, 
18.89, 7.57, 0.8, 0.01, 20.23, 11.29, 7.55, 3.24, 0.54, 0.12, 
0.03, 53.27, 46.82, 38.17, 26.77, 11.59, 2.23, 0.07, 69.25, 63.55, 
56.34, 40.95, 19.35, 2.4, 0.05, 75.8, 68.21, 62.82, 40.33, 11.73, 
0.82, 0.04, 85.75, 82.82, 74.29, 46.63, 9.36, 0.24, 0.05, 71.65, 
66.54, 56.63, 33.96, 6.33, 0.19, 0.03, 85.43, 86.49, 75.73, 51.62, 
15.16, 1.05, 0.01, 92.44, 90.13, 85.92, 72.06, 30.08, 3.15, 0.12
), Sample = c("1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", 
"1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", 
"1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", 
"1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 4DA", 
"1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", 
"5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", 
"5mer 0DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", 
"5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", 
"5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -63L))
```

[image: Graph image]

Comment: `ggline` comes from what package? When using a non-base function, please start the scripts with calls to library() to load the required packages. What is the model you are fitting? Can you post fitting code?

Comment: That is from ggpubr. All the libraries I load for a session are:library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(drc)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggh4x)
library(gridExtra)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)     I am trying to fit a sigmoidal line of best fit (since this is a titration curve) but I am unsure of what code to use for such a line of best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do without the fitted line in the legend, here is a way but with packages `ggplot2` and `scales`, not with package `ggpubr`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)
})

ggplot(Titration.Aug.9, aes(x = Dilution, y = `X..bound`)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = "log10",
    breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
    minor_breaks = 10^(seq(0, 7, by = 0.25))) +
  scale_color_brewer(type="Sample",palette="Set1") +
  labs(x="Dilution",y="% Bound") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!! Would you happen to know how to smooth out the graph lines (for example 1mer 0DA a smooth line?)

Comment: @Regan You would have to have a model for those data, for instance splines. That is (almost) entirely dependent on subject-matter knowledge. Is there a theoretical sigmoidal model? My knowledge of chemistry is not enough to answer this question of mine.

Comment: I think I figured it out! Thank you!! :) I really appreciate your time!